# Why is my Exchange ResolveNames Search only returning 100 rows?

Tags: c#, max, exchangewebservices

I am using  Exchange Web Services [the following code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa493895%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) to download a bunch of records from our exchange server.

The issue is that based on my partial search string, I should get back 500 rows, but it only returns 100 records.  I [see some documentation that 100 is the default max records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/exchangewebservices.resolvenamestype%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) but I don't see any property or anywhere to change that default to a higher number.

Is there any way to change this value to > 100 ?

Comment: It appears that the limit is a deliberate governor on the method, possibly to limit denial of service attacks on the server. You may have to wrie a loop and simply live with retrieving 100 rows at a time. What business problem ae you addressing?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - right now I have a loop to do the trick but it take 20 times longer that it would have to if it just supported changing the max records property somewhere . . .  my business problem is that I need to download information around all of our conference rooms.  They all start with the same prefix in Exchange Address List, but there are more than 100 rooms . .

Comment: You have a legitimate business case that could be construed as a hostile attack. I am nothing near being an expert on Exchange Server, but is the performance really an issue? Have you profiled to verify the bottleneck?

Comment: Why don't you try the [EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh532566%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) approach? The [`ResolveNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563518%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) web service operation returns a maximum of 100 candidates. you can't change this (very likely) hard-coded limit.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN documentation, 100 is not the "default max records", rather it is the "max records" and appears to be a hardcoded limit as Alex mentions above.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the hard max limit is 100. This can not be changed or worked around. However, there is a Boolean flag returned telling you if there were more than 100 matching names. This way you can tell your user to refine their search further.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.nameresolutioncollection.includesallresolutions%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx